# How can I iterate through an Arraylist in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, arraylist

I am making an android studio app and I want it to make a TextView disappear when I say a certain phrase. The code saves everything I say into an array list. I want to see if it includes the phrase.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case  100:

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                boolean yes = Arrays.asList(result.get(0)).contains(InputActivity.Item1);
                    if(yes == true){
                        result1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
for(String s:result){
if(s.equals(InputActivity.Item1)){
   //hide text view
}
}
```

Comment: I've tried almost everything on stack overflow, but the TextView doesn't disappear. I can print out what I've said by using `result.get()` but I can't get the text view to disappear

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If the arraylist contains what do you want to hide the textview?

Comment: There is an edit text in the previous activity, and if the text that is inputted in the edit text is in the ArrayList, I want the TextView to dissapear

Comment: And why is it stored like a boolean, or that isnt the edit text text?

Comment: Man, it is not working doesnt say me anything, try to toast the variables, DEBUG

Comment: Never mind, I got it to work. It was an issue with the positioning of the values in the array list.